# Batch operation over thousands of aggregates in CQRS system, do people do that?

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm working on an application for managing bank credit cards.
CQRS and Event Sourcing architecture was chosen for the app.
The most important aggregate in the app is `CreditCard` which controls the credit card lifecycle.
It looks something like:

```
class CreditCard {
   private int status;
   public void activate() {...}
   public void deactivate () {...}
   ...
}
```

Its `activate` and `deactivate` methods protects credit card invariants and publish `CardActivatedEvent` and `CardDeactivatedEvent`, respectively, if the invocation of the method succeeds.
We store these events in the event store for later aggregate reconstruction on the command side.
We apply these events to various views.
We use these events to notify other third party systems.
All good for now.

Recently, we got a new requirement to charge all active credit cards on monthly basis.

My first instinct was, ok we can add `charge` method to the same `CreditCard` aggregate.
This method can check some invariants relevant to charging. Like, is the card in correct status for charging, was it charged already, etc.
On successful invocation, this method can publish `CardChargedEvent`.
Then we can create some process manager which will once per month query view side for active credit cards to get their IDs.
Having these IDs, the process manager can issue multiple charge commands (one per credit card aggregate) to the command side.
For each charge command received, the command side will reconstruct `CreditCard` aggregate object and call it's `charge` method.
The only problem is that this approach looks quite inefficient. Especially regarding database roundtrips on the command side (one read and one write per aggregate instance).
If we take into the equation that we can easily have 100k plus credit cards in our app, this roundtrip overhead starts looking to me as a bit of a problem.

Does anyone have any experience with batch operations on CQRS/ES systems?
Is my concern valid?
What to do in such cases?
How you implement batches in CQRS systems?

One alternative that pops to my mind is that for charging use case I ditch CQRS/ES/DDD principles, and implement the whole thing using stored procedures on one of our view databases. This procedure can search for suitable credit cards in the credit card view table and populate the "to be charged queue" table with records found. Then I can have some external process that reads this second table and do whatever it needs to do.

Comment: How about publishing an `EndOfMonth` event which upon being handled writes 100k `ChargeCreditCard` commands to be handled in a queue. Then you have a processor that handles those commands one by one in their own transaction? I mean, it will take longer to process than a single DB update command for sure, but a single batch process would also put contention on ALL cards in a single tx.

Comment: This starts looking to me as streaming vs. batch dilemma. Either way I will end up with 100k ```CardChargedEvent``` events in some broker queue or 100k ```CardCharged``` records in a database. I still need to take this 100k events/records into memory and propagate them (via REST api) to third party billing system. The question remains, what is the most optimal way to come up with these 100k ```CardCharged``` events/records in the first place.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what I'm saying. Once all commands are written to a queue they get processed one by one. There's no need to bring all your CreditCard ARs in memory nor generate and publish the CardCharged events all at once. How long could it take to generate and write these 100k commands? Maybe 2-3 secs?

Comment: The only other way I could think of doing that is to have a durable processor that polls the cards not charged and destroys or mark itself as done once it processed all cards. That way you never have 100k objects in memory and can decide how big the batches are.

Comment: E.g. at the end of every month you have a scheduled process that creates another job to run until all cards are processed.

Comment: "Once all commands are written to a queue they get processed one by one". How do you see this processing step for each individual command? I see it like this: ```ChargeCreditCard``` command is dispatched to ```ChargeCreditCardCommandHandler```. This handler loads corresponding ```CreditCard``` aggregate into memory and calls ```charge``` method on it. This method checks some invariants (e.g. checks that card is not charged already) and publishes ```CardChargedEvent``` on success. This event is then stored in event store and views are updated accordingly.

Comment: Yeah that's what I had in mind. Do you see any issues with that? You can always try to parallelize the command processing as well.

Comment: I will try it. Will let you know how this went. Thx for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar and have done it like plalx suggested - but since I'm using CosmosDB as my event store, it's taking up a considerable amount of RUs to retrieve events from a snapshot (around 30ish average) + inserting the newer event. Have you done it like that? Or have you went with the queue approach?

Answer (score -1):

> Recently, we got a new requirement to charge all active credit cards on monthly basis.  My first instinct was, ok we can add charge method to the same CreditCard aggregate.

I think this is where the design flaw happens.

Your `CreditCard` aggregate was designed with a specific use case in mind:

> The most important aggregate in the app is CreditCard which controls the credit card lifecycle.

Charging the credit card is not part of the credit card lifecycle. Whether it happens or not depends on the credit card state, but charging (successfully) the credit card will not change the state of your domain object. It should not interact with the CreditCard domain aggregate, as the purpose of your aggregate is to enforce business rules when changing your state. You should ask yourself: what aggregate is changed when charging a credit card ?

The answer to this question depends on the rest of your domain model and business cases, but it has more to do to with stuff like account balance or credit authorization than the card itself. You could implement like this:

- A batch process working monthly would query your CreditCard aggregate for active cards, then try to charge all customers for their monthly fees by sending a command to the AccountBalance aggregate ;
- The AccountBalance aggregate would raise a BalanceChangedEvent if the customer has enough money, or a CreditAuthorizationRequiredEvent if not, temporarily freezing the account until the credit was authorized or rejected ;
- A CreditAuthorization aggregate could either allow or deny the credit, based on credit allowance business rules, raising events accordingly ;
- The AccountBalance aggregate would unfreeze the account, changing the balance or not based on the outcome, eventually raising or not the BalanceChangedEvent ;
- The CreditCard aggregate would register to the CreditDeniedEvent to deactivate the credit card because the customer was not able to pay the fees ;

... and so on ...